# Let S be the set consisting of all sequences of 0's and 1's.How to prove that $S \sim R$?

Tags: real-analysis

$$
S = \lbrace(a_1, a_2, a_3, . . .) : a_n = 0\ or\ 1\rbrace
$$
Recently, I was self-study Understanding of Analysis.I know that S is uncountable.However,I find many solution state that $S \sim R$.I spent a lot of time but didn't know how to prove it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint:think of the binary expansion of a real number between 0 and 1.$x=sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{a_n} {2^{n}} $, where $a_{n}\in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: @belkacemabderrahmane Thanks, now I know what to do.